# systemd in LXC endlessly trying to umount pam_mount home

Tags: mount, 15.04, lxc, pam, systemd

I use the following `$HOME/.pam_mount.conf.xml` to mount an LXC container filesystem when I log in via SSH:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE pam_mount SYSTEM "pam_mount.conf.xml.dtd">
<!--
        See pam_mount.conf(5) for a description.
-->

<pam_mount>

                <!-- debug should come before everything else,
                since this file is still processed in a single pass
                from top-to-bottom -->

<debug enable="0" />

                <!-- Volume definitions -->

<volume
    user="user" path="/dev/sda2" mountpoint="/var/lib/lxc/container"
    fstype="crypt" options="exec,fsck" />
<volume
    user="user" mountpoint="/home/user.orig"
    path="/home/user" options="nosuid,nodev,bind" />
<volume
    user="user" mountpoint="~"
    path="/var/lib/lxc/container/rootfs/home/user"
    options="nosuid,nodev,bind" />


                <!-- pam_mount parameters: General tunables -->

</pam_mount>
```

Then I start the LXC container after logging in.  Since the upgrade to Ubuntu vivid, the container's `/var/log/syslog` is flooded with the following log sequence:

```
Jun  1 21:09:43 container systemd[1]: Unit home-user.mount is bound to inactive unit dev-mapper-_dev_sda2.device. Stopping, too.
Jun  1 21:09:43 container systemd[1]: Unmounting /home/user...
Jun  1 21:09:44 container umount[5799]: umount: /home/user: target is busy
Jun  1 21:09:44 container umount[5799]: (In some cases useful info about processes that
Jun  1 21:09:44 container umount[5799]: use the device is found by lsof(8) or fuser(1).)
Jun  1 21:09:44 container systemd[1]: home-user.mount mount process exited, code=exited status=32
Jun  1 21:09:44 container systemd[1]: Failed unmounting /home/user.
```

How can I address this?  Is there someway to tell the container's systemd not to manage that mount?

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue with systemd. If the device is brought up in initramfs then it gets a SYSTEMD_STATUS=0 and is always seen as an inactive device. I have the same issue with a custom initramfs that does not have an embeded systemd. I have been trying to find some way online to make udev and systemd aware that the device is actually started and change its status but it seams like a dead end.

Many of the posts ive seen from the devs also are discouraging as they don't see this as a problem.